# "make" stops during installation of tty0tty (null-modem emulator)

Tags: compiling, opensuse, kernel-modules

I try to [install tty0tty a null-modem emulatom](https://askubuntu.com/a/588806) like in the linked installation guide, but I have a problem at "3. Build the kernel module from provided source":

```
user@linux-bmne:/run/media/.../Downloads/tty0tty-1.2/module> make
make -C /lib/modules/3.16.7-29-desktop/build M=/run/media/.../Downloads/tty0tty-1.2/module modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/lib/modules/3.16.7-29-desktop/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'modules'. Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/lib/modules/3.16.7-29-desktop/build'
Makefile:26: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Yes, the makefile is in the folder `module`. Also `/lib/modules/3.16.7-29-desktop/build` exit (after I `mkdir build` in `3.16.7-29-desktop`). You can have a look at the folder structure of tty0tty [here](https://github.com/freemed/tty0tty) (It is very simple). I also tried out `sudo make`, but It made no difference.

The problem `No rule to make target` seems to be common, but I does not found a matching solution in this case. I do not know if this is helpful, but my System is open suse 13.2 x86_64.

I would be thankful for your help.

Comment: the target modules is not defined in the Makefile.

Comment: @Winston That's actually not the issue: the issue is that the expected makefile is missing. The target `modules` needs to exist in `/lib/modules/3.16.7-29-desktop/build`, not in the makefiles distributed with tty0tty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a kernel module, you need some header files which are generated during the build of the main kernel image. The makefile expects those headers to be available under `/lib/modules/3.16.7-29-desktop/build` where the `3.16.7-29-desktop` is determined from your running kernel. Together with the header files, there's a makefile which can be used to build third-party modules. The makefile in `module` calls that makefile, but it isn't present on your system.

You need to install the kernel headers for your system. On OpenSUSE, that's the [`kernel-devel`](http://software.opensuse.org/package/kernel-devel) package. On most distributions, `/lib/modules/VERSION/build` is a symbolic link to where the kernel header tree is located. I don't know if OpenSUSE does this; if it doesn't, then either create the symbolic link or pass the actual location of the headers (the directory containing files `Makefile` and `Module.symvers` and subdirectories `include` and `arch`) as an argument to `make`

```
make KERNELDIR=/path/to/kernel-headers
```

The latter method is what you'll need to use if you want to build the module for a kernel version that isn't the one that's currently running.

Comment: Well thanks, but there is a little problem: I downloaded and installed the `kernel-devel` package for my version (13.2), but the header files are NOT in the `3.16.7-29-desktop` folder, but in another (`4.1.12-1-default`), so I can only build the module `tty0tty` for this (default)version. Can the module also run on version `3.16.7-29-desktop` ?

Comment: @goulashsoup Usually, no, you need the kernel headers for the right version. (Sometimes it works, often it doesn't.) RPM can have multiple versions of the same package, is a `3.16.7-29-desktop` version of the package available?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I installed the suitable header files for this Version